# Get Page Title from Loaded WebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, webview, label, self

I'm trying to get to change the UILabel pageTitle to whatever the title of the page displayed on the UIWebView is. I'm returning no warnings or errors, it just simply isn't changing.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    UIWebView *_webView;
    UILabel *_pageTitle;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *pageTitle;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    self.pageTitle.text = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
    [_webView setDelegate:self];

}
```

**Screenshot of IB**

[image: Screenshot of IB]

Comment: Have you remembered to set the delegate of your UIWebView to the view controller so that webViewDidFinishLoad: is called?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `[_webView setDelegate:self];` under `viewdidLoad`/`loadView` so it can call the UIWebViewDelegate